# display all the elements of an array in a single table cell using for loop

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, the table `table_log` where I get the data from has 3 columns but I only need: (1) `id` (2) `start` (3) `end`. there are multiple logs with the same id and different start and end values. I'm trying to get the start values so I've placed said values in an array `storage`. Now, what I'm trying to do is place all values in the arrow in a single cell in the table but only the first value `[0]` appears not unless I make another column. How can I resolve this?

Query:

```
$logs = mysql_query("SELECT start FROM table_log WHERE id = '". $resultID."'");
$storage = Array();
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($logs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storage[] =  $res['start'];  
}
```

Loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($res); ++$i) {
    if(count($res) > $i) {                          
        $start_log = " $storage[$i] <br>";
    }
}

$data .= "<td>". $start_log ."</td>";
```

Database:

```
id | start | end
01 | 10:00 | 11:00
01 | 12:00 | 01:00
01 | 03:00 | 03:30
```

Needed Output:

```
id | start | end
01 | 10:00 | 11:00
   | 12:00 | 01:00
   | 03:00 | 03:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all - use same variable names ($storage & $storeArray & $res)
- Secondly - mysql is removed in php7, instead try to make mysqli or PDO;
- Do you want outputting only start times or all data???

---

```
$logs = mysql_query("SELECT start FROM table_log WHERE id = $resultID");
$storage = Array(); // from PHP5.6 use fetch_all
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($logs)) { 
    $storage[] =  $res['start'];
}
$output = "<div><b>$resultID:</b>". implode (' | ', $storage) ."</div>";
```

Comment: whoops thanks for pointing that out. i fixed it and did what you suggested but it's still doing the same thing? only the first element is appearing for some reason

Comment: i'm trying out the start time first since i thought it'd be the same for the end time also.

Comment: @Mel Better now?

Answer (score 0):

```
                 <?php
                      $logs = mysql_query("SELECT start FROM table_log WHERE id =$resultID");
                     while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($logs)) {
                      ?>
                     <table>
                      <tr>
                     <th>id</th>
                    <th>start</th>
                     <th>end</th>
                        </tr>
                       <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $res['id'];</td>
                   <td><?php echo $res['start'];</td>
                   <td><?php echo $res['end'];</td>
                     </tr> 
                   </table>
                      <?php     
                          }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it! this one worked for me :)

```
$start_log = "";
$j = 1;
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($logs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storage[] =  $res['start'];  
    $j++;
}

for($i = 0; $i<=$ctr; $i++) {           
   $start_log .= " $storage[$i] <br>";
}
```